# match with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to use match and a regular expression to split a string into an array.

Example:

```
var strdoc = '<p>noi dung</p>bài viết đúng.Đó thực sự là, cuối cùng';
var arrdocobj = strdoc.match(/(<.+?>)|(\s)|(\w+)(.+?)/g);
```

When I do `console.log arrdocobj`, it results in

```
["<p>", "noi ", "dung<", "p>", "bà", "i ", "viế", "t ", "ng.", " ", "thự", "c ", "sự", " ", "là", " ", "cuố", "i ", "cù", "ng"]
```

How can I split the string to an array like this

```
["<p>", "noi"," ", "dung", "<p>","bài"," ","viết"," ","đúng",".","Đó"," ","thực"," ","sự"," ","là", "," ," ","cuối"," ","cùng"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could maybe use something like that?

```
var strdoc = '<p>noi dung</p>tiêu đề bài viết đúng';
var arrdocobj = strdoc.match(/<[^>]+>|\S+?(?= |$|<)/g);
```

I was looking into using the `\b` with the unicode flag, but I guess it isn't available in JS, so I used `(?= |$|<)` to emulate the word boundary.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QLzuy/)

EDIT: As per edit of question:

```
<[^>]+>|[^ .,!?:<]+(?=[ .,!?:<]|$)|.
```

might do the trick.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QLzuy/3/).

I just added a few more punctuations and the `|.` for the remaining stuff to match.

Comment: @user1822688 Huh, so you want the spaces and punctuation?

Comment: @user1822688 Can you try to see if the new regex suits you?

Comment: @user1822688 Woah, I never thought I would save someone's life one day xD You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I thing the following regex does what you are asking in your edit:

```
    var strdoc = '<p>noi dung</p>bài viết đúng.Đó thực sự là, cuối cùng';
    var arrdocobj = strdoc.match(/<[^>]+>|[\s]+|[^\s<]+/g);
```

Unfortunatly JavaScript does not support Unicode categories like \p{L} for any Unicode Letter